# Existe uma maneira de parar um tweening no ROBLOX studio?

Tags: lua

Eu quero um comando que pare um tweening no ROBLOX studio, por exemplo:

```
frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 0),
    "Out", "Quad", 1)
```

Mas ao receber alguma condição, tem alguma maneira de parar esse tweening?

Answer (score 0):

No momento não é possível, mas definindo o [quinto](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiObject/TweenPosition#firstHeading) (nativamente sexto) argumento dessa chamada se torna possível substituir o seu tweening por outro.

(Infelizmente não tem como eu saber se o exemplo funciona.)

### **Exemplo de como parar um tweening** (não testado):

```
frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 0),
    "Out", "Quad", 1, true);

frame:TweenPosition(frame.Position,
    "Out", "Quad", 0, --[=[opcional]=]true);
```

Documentação:

- [API:Class/GuiObject - Roblox Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiObject)
- [API:Class/GuiObject/TweenPosition - Roblox Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiObject/TweenPosition)

Comment: não funcionou :(

Comment: @arthurgps Não houve nenhum erro? Desculpe, não entendo de Roblox :/ .

Comment: não houve nenhum erro,mas não parou o tweening

Comment: @arthurgps Usou o quinto argumento `true` como no exemplo? Tem que ser ambas chamadas.

Comment: sim,eu usei o true

Comment: @arthurgps2 Tenta logar os retornos do último tweening? `print(frame:TweenPosition(frame.Position, "Out", "Quad", 0, true));`, pode dizer o que loga? Se o primeiro retorno for `false`, o primero tweening não está podendo ser substituído, eu acho.